# Prestashop1.6 Change Default Product thickbox with watermark

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

In product.tpl i managed to change the default size of thickbox by editing this code

```
href="{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $imageIds, 'thickbox_default')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}"
```

to

```
href="{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $imageIds, '')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}"
```

now the problem is the watermark is not working, Note that i used prestashops default watermark module.

Comment: third parameter of getImageLink method is the image type which are managed under BO->preference->images, the 3rd param is optional and if its blank the original image will be returned. I think the watermark module draw the watermark only on the images other than the original one. So please try creating new image type and pass newly created image type to the 3rd param of getImageLink method

Comment: Yes it is a great solution but the problem there is the auto generation of prestashop images produce a lot of white space, i only want to show the original size of the image.

Comment: im sorry regarding the white space issue - i found some topics in presta forums related to white space issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prestashop provides a feature called image types where we can created custom image type with providing width, height and the image type is used for (category, product,manufacture etc..) and we can use this image type in tpl or php codes wherever required.

Watermark module draws the watermark for all image types except original image. So for your case we can create a new image type called custom_default and we can use this in your tpl file

```
getImageLink($name, $ids, $type = null)
```

getimagelink method accepts 3 parameters and the 3rd param is for image type and not required and is null by default. So if we pass the 3rd param the image with the provided type will be returned otherwise original image will be returned. So just modify your tpl code by passing our new image type as the value for 3rd param

```
href="{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $imageIds, 'custom_default')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}"
```